# SHGetValue returns 2 when querying UAC value

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mingw, uac

I would like to check the UAC configuration settings of windows. And thus recover the parameters of the UAC in the registry keys.

I used the windows `SHGetValue` function but the status always returns me 2 without any information.

I use C++11, MinGW and windows.

My code is :

```
DWORD dwStatus;
  LPCSTR pszSubKey= "HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
  LPCSTR pszValue="";
  DWORD  pdwType=REG_SZ;
  PVOID  pvData[63];
  DWORD  pcbData;
  pcbData=sizeof(pvData);

  dwStatus=SHGetValueA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pszSubKey, pszValue, &pdwType, pvData, &pcbData);

  //Here dwStatus = 2
  // pvData = 0x11fd0b2
  // pcbData = 504
```

Comment: Not sure on the shell abstractions. Maybe try the `Winreg.h` API's, see which returns an error (`RegOpenKey`, `RegQueryValueEx`, etc.)  and if it is more detailed.

Comment: *"... the status always returns me 2 without any information ..."* - `SHGetValue` returns a [`LSTATUS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shgetvaluea). I believe that is. `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. I believe you are asking for a key, subkey or value that does not exist. One of the folks more current with the Win32 API can probably say more.

Comment: `HKLM` is not the name of a registry key, it's an abbreviation for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` which you're already passing to `SHGetValue` as the first parameter.

Comment: @jww the status with compiler MinGW is a DWORD, and I corrected my error with the answer of Jonathan thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What specific key you are trying to read? I am not an expert on win32 API so I don't know whether there is a way to read a set of keys at once (**Edit:** I think there are`RegEnumValue/RegEnumValueA` functions for this purpose). Here is an example that shows how you can read "EnableLUA" or any other key from that path:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <shlwapi.h>


bool ReadUACRegistryKey(char* key, DWORD &keyValue)
{
    LPCTSTR pszSubKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
    LPCTSTR pszValue = key;

    //  don't care
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    DWORD dwValue = 0;

    //  
    DWORD dwValueSize = sizeof(dwValue);

    int retval = SHGetValue( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pszSubKey, key, &dwType, &dwValue, &dwValueSize);
    if ( retval != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return false;
    }

    keyValue = dwValue;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD keyValue;
    char* key = "EnableLUA";  //  "EnableSecureUIAPaths" etc..;
    if (ReadUACRegistryKey(key, keyValue))
    {
        std::cout << "Successfully readed key " << key << ", value:" << keyValue << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to read value of key " << key << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Also keep in mind that value of read key value is stored in value parameter, not in the return value of the function.

**Edit**: Answer of the the op's comment *"I want use FilterAdministratorToken but is disable by default how give it back enable .?"*. Keep in mind that your process need to have admin rights to perform these operation.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <shlwapi.h>


bool ReadUACRegistryKey(char* key, DWORD &keyValue)
{
    LPCTSTR pszSubKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
    LPCTSTR pszValue = key;

    //  don't care
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    DWORD dwValue = 0;

    //  
    DWORD dwValueSize = sizeof(dwValue);

    int retval = SHGetValue( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pszSubKey, key, &dwType, &dwValue, &dwValueSize);
    if ( retval != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return false;
    }

    keyValue = dwValue;
    return true;
}

bool EnableFilterAdministratorToken()
{
    //  first check if its already enabled or not
    DWORD val;
    if (ReadUACRegistryKey("FilterAdministratorToken", val))
    {
        if (val == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "FilterAdministratorToken is already enabled" << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to read key" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }


    //  its not enabled, we need to enable it manually
    //  obtain a handle to reg key
    HKEY hKey;
    int retval = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hKey);
    if (retval != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //  we are unable to obtain a handle to reg key
        std::cout << "Unable to obtain handle to reg key" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }


    DWORD enabledValue = 1;
    retval = RegSetValueExA(hKey, "FilterAdministratorToken", 0, REG_DWORD, (BYTE*) &enabledValue, sizeof(DWORD));
    if (retval != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //  some error occured
        std::cout << "Some error occured during setting the key value" << std::endl;
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Successfully changed key value" << std::endl;
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    if (EnableFilterAdministratorToken())
    {
        std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want use FilterAdministratorToken but is disable by default how give it back
 enable .?